# Parse XML data and import them into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I have a xml array. http://laravel.io/bin/yGzD8#17 and i have a mysql table. Two of them have same column names. I want to add datas to mysql table from xml. But i dont want to use all of column names in mysql insert into query. I want to basic solution that loops all xml nodes and insert it into mysql. I dont want full of code. I want to know how can i do it. I tried to loop all values but i cant fetch column names in xml. My codes in below. I can reach values but i want to reach node names.

```
  if( ! $xml = simplexml_load_file('cari.xml') )
{
    echo 'unable to load XML file';
}
else
{
  foreach( $xml as $element)
   {
       echo "BLKODU =>".$element->BLKODU." </br>";
       echo "CARIKODU =>".$element->CARIKODU." </br>";
       echo "TICARI_UNVANI =>".$element->TICARI_UNVANI." </br>";
       echo "ILI_1 =>".$element->ILI_1." </br>";
       echo "----------------"."</br>";

}
```

Comment: Please do a _var\_dump($xml)_ after you have loaded the XML data and show it us.

Comment: http://laravel.io/bin/52bPy and its my xml file http://merihdursun.com.tr/cari.xml

Comment: `$element->getName();`?

Comment: It returns string "Table"

Comment: http://laravel.io/bin/kWzOE Solved.